# Enable change/reset password on Flutter App with Azure B2c

Tags: azure, flutter, dart, azure-ad-b2c, appauth

I am trying to enable the functionality to change/reset the password in a Flutter App with Azure B2C. Changing the password should be achieved via a "change password button" on the user profile page, the password reset via "Forgot your password?" on the b2clogin.com page.

I am using [flutter_appauth](https://github.com/hitshydev/flutter_appauth) for the login. The user login works as expected with the following code and the user is redirected to the b2clogin.com page.

```
      result = await appauth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
        AuthorizationTokenRequest(AppConfig.instance.values.clientId,
          AppConfig.instance.values.redirectUrl,
          serviceConfiguration: AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(AppConfig.instance.values.authorizationEndpoint,AppConfig.instance.values.tokenEndpoint),
          scopes: AppConfig.instance.values.scopes),
  );
```

But when the user clicks on "Forgot your password?", the redirection to the b2c password reset page is missing. How can I link the button to my password reset user flow?

Any ideas how I can trigger the "b2c change password" functionality with a button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default "forgot password" flow will throw an error back to the application. There is now a newer way to send the user directly to "forgot password" step as part of the "combined sign up and sign in" journey.

The steps to set that up are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#self-service-password-reset-recommended) for custom policy, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#self-service-password-reset-recommended) for user flows.